# Capturar cookies desdeuna petición en axios o fecth con react native

Tags: react-native, axios, fetch, cookies

Necesito hacer una petición con axios o con fetch pero que la respuesta pueda capturar las cookies que se generan desde react native. He intentado de varias formas pero no he podido aún.

Comment: puedes obtenerlos  de los header de la respuesta https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/headers

Comment: No me devuelve las cookies ya eso lo intente:

`Headers {
  "map": Object {
    "cache-control": "public, max-age=0",
    "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
    "date": "Thu, 15 Apr 2021 20:15:11 GMT",
    "server": "nginx",
    "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
    "x-aspnet-version": "4.0.30319",
    "x-powered-by": "ASP.NET",
    "x-reqs-limit": "CHECK",
  },
}`

eso es lo que me devuelve

Comment: Si es tu api , enviale las cookies en tu respuesta. Si es de otro capaz lo prohibio o no tiene cookies.

Comment: No es mi api, es de una pagina de comercio, pero nunca me devuelve una cookie, ni a eso ni a nada. Y por el navegador puedo ver sus cookies, es que de hecho necesito esa cookie para hacer todo lo que deseo dentro de la pagina. Habrá alguna forma de hacerlo?